# Jaspersoft studio - 2 independent numerations

Tags: jasper-reports

I create report with Jaspersoft Studio. I want to have 2 independent numerations in page footer for example:

```
Page 1 -> 1 of 3
Page 2 -> 2 of 3
Page 3 -> 3 of 3
Page 4 -> 1 of 2
Page 5 -> 2 of 2
```

I don't know how many pages will be in in first numeration and how many will be in second one, but I know that second numeration will have 1 page less.

Please help.